# How can I get SSE rounding in a Delphi version prior to XE2?

Tags: delphi, rounding, delphi-2007, sse

How can I get XE2 style rounding in the previous Delphi versions, so with SSE ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What changed in XE2?

Comment: SSE rounding. But I ask this to share my knowledge, (I've edited the title.)

Comment: SSE rouding but only if the target is win64...IIRC the rtl

Comment: You'd want to test for availability of SSE unit. And your question makes no mention of 64 bit targets. You really ought to explain the motivation in the question.

Comment: I wished to test the feature "Answer to your own question" of SO. Additionally it's usefull...The question looks vague bacause people doesn't know that what is made in the RTl for rouding if target is 64bit on XE2 can also be made in any previous Delphi version (so implicitely with a 32 bit target)...

Comment: This feature of SO doesn't need testing. It is known to work. You are still expected to abide by the guidelines of what makes a good question. Please edit the question appropriately.

Comment: IT's worse than that, any gain in performance in a specific  environment will be totally offset by the decrease in comprehensibility in a real world environment. This would be a good slap round the head in a peer review, and a chat with your manager about where you are wasting his valuable resources.

Comment: @Tony: I understand but a bench of pro testers who make a test in a loop in a console app won't get relevant hints about how the opt version is best...just read my answer.

Comment: @Tony If you are writing floating point intensive code then including bespoke asm can be worthwhile. Obviously there's a trade off but if your clients want your program to go faster, and using asm can make it go faster, then trade off can be worth while. I for one use a lot of bespoke x87 asm in my app. It gives around 5% speed up. Not much. But, it also doesn't cost me because it never changes. Arithmetic is like that. Once you have got it right, you never need to change it.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it more clear what you are after. Things like: Why is SSE rounding important? How does it differ from rounding in previous Delphi versions?

Comment: @az01 point missed, it's not the arithmetic changing that should concern us, it's the definition of right. Given that definition apparently did change. By the way 5% of what and at what cost, optimisation is not free. There is no best, there's suits my particular circumstance at this moment.

Comment: I would have more of an approach like asking your manager if your company can upgrade to XE2 (or XE3)

Comment: @Jerry You don't get SSE codegen on XE2 automatically. Only for 64 bit. If you want SSE on 32 bit you still need to do it yourself. This is not about XE2, it's about the 64 bit compiler. The question is just so vague and imprecise.

Answer (score 2):

Inline Delphi assembly supports SSE instructions since a while.
two overloaded versions are possible: for single and double.
In addition two versions are possible: input as Parameter or as pointer.
This version is particularly faster than the native Round()/Trunc() methods.

To round you have:

```
Function RoundSSE(Value: Single): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // additional PUSH/POP pointer stack added automatically
  CVTSS2SI  EAX, Value
End;

Function RoundSSE(Value: Double): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // additional PUSH/POP pointer stack added automatically
  MOVQ      XMM0,Value
  CVTSD2SI  EAX, XMM0
End;

Function RoundMEM_SSE(Var Value: Single): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // as written, fatest version
  CVTSS2SI  EAX, [Value]
End;

Function RoundMEM_SSE(Var Value: Double): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // as written, fatest version
  CVTSD2SI  EAX, [Value]
End;
```

To truncate you have the same with CVTTSS2SI / CVTTSD2SI:

```
Function TruncSSE(Value: Single): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // additional PUSH/POP pointer stack added automatically
  CVTTSS2SI  EAX, Value
End;

Function TruncSSE(Value: Double): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // additional PUSH/POP pointer stack added automatically
  MOVQ      XMM0,Value
  CVTTSD2SI  EAX, XMM0
End;

Function TruncMEM_SSE(Var Value: Single): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // as written, fatest version
  CVTTSS2SI  EAX, [Value]
End;

Function TruncMEM_SSE(Var Value: Double): Integer; Overload;
Asm
  // as written, fatest version
  CVTTSD2SI  EAX, [Value]
End;
```

To Floor, Ceil, use respectively *TruncMEM_SSE(value)* and *RoundSSE(value + 0.5)*.
These functions will give you a 20% perf gain. It has been tested in
loops and in a real program (with a memory cache filled/ an instruction cache filled, so it can be considered as a real-life test).

Comment: Given I want accuracy to x decimal places, why would I be using Singles and Doubles???

Comment: In my trivial benchmark, the double precision `RoundSSE` is 3 times slower than the RTL's `Round`. This is of course for 32 bit code. I'm using XE2. With default project's Release build options.

Comment: @az01 what's the point of it then? I can get inaccurate results really fast, can't help feel but you've stumbled straight into being too clever territory with this. I can imagine my colleagues disgruntlement if I started banging assembly in the middle of the code base, not pretty at all.

Comment: @Tony No, the results are accurate. But my simple test had this code in the answer being 3 times slower than the equivalent RTL unit. I'm finding it hard to imagine a real-world situation where Round or Trunc are the bottleneck.

Comment: @DH does "prior to XE2?" such as in the title makes sense for you when you say "I'm using XE2".

Comment: @az01 No need to insult me. The code that the 32 bit compiler uses for `Round` hasn't changed in living memory. So far as I can tell, this code is slower than the built in code! Where's your benchmark code?

Comment: Yes it hasn't changed, and that's the whole purpose of the subject: it can be faster! So what now: Yet another big misunderstanding !

Comment: Right, the version where you use a var param is faster than RTL's `Round`. So what's needed is to find a way to write this without needing to use a var param.

Comment: Don't give up. Run times for my test program are the same in 2010 and XE2. There's no problem with using XE2 32 bit for benchmarking this. It's the same old compiler and the same old RTL. What I've seen is that `RoundSSE` is really slow, and `RoundMEM_SSE` is slightly faster than the x87 based RTL `Round`. You think I'm stupid? Why?

Comment: Mostly what this highlights is the extreme cost of pushing the double precision value onto the stack in the param passed by value overloads for double arguments. If, for `const` params the compiler passed the address of the value, then you'd not be pushed towards that rather strange feeling use of `var` for what is logically a by value parameter. The other thing it points out is that `Round` is simply astoundingly fast. My computer can do a billion `Round` calls in 3 seconds. So for SSE to help, you'd need a program that did nothing other than call `Round`. Not likely.

Comment: Now, you berated me and called me "stupid" in this thread. For using XE2 32 bit for my trials. Which has the same runtime performance as Delphi 2010 and even Delphi 6. If there's any stupidity, it's not my use of XE2. In a comment that was removed you said "why do you suck?" Well, I don't think I do. You need to take a look in the mirror and consider your attitude. Statements like that are never acceptable.

Comment: Finally, I have learnt something useful in this thread. Namely that SSE instructions for rounding are a little faster than x87 instructions, but that the 32 bit compiler's ABI for 8 byte reals makes it awkward to take advantage of that. So thank you for giving me the opportunity to learn. I always appreciate that. I'm sure you knew these particulars already. It's really a shame that you didn't elucidate them clearly in the Q&A. The Q needs to state the problem precisely. And the A needs to include much more detail, and the benchmarks. This could be a good Q&A, but at the moment is lacking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 32 bit compiler will NOT emit these SSE instructions. I hope you know this.

Comment: @user3764855 I know that certainly.